# How to stop TFTP server using TFTPy on Python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tftp

I need to use TFTP server on Python and I try to use TFTPy module for it.  Server works perfect, but I can't stop it in moment as I wish.

Python v3.7, TFTPy v 0.8.0, Windows 10x64. I tried to write simple code and using threads but nothing changed.

```
import tftpy
import time
server = tftpy.TftpServer('C:/Users/MyUSER/Downloads/FTPS/')
server.listen('127.0.0.1', 69)
time.sleep(5)
server.stop(True)
```

and more complex using threads:

```
import tftpy
import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime


tftp_ip_addr = '127.0.0.1'
tftp_folder = 'C:/Users/MyUSER/Downloads/FTPS/'


class PyTFTPServer(object):
    def __init__(self, tftp_ip_addr, tftp_folder):
        self.tftp_ip_addr = tftp_ip_addr
        self.tftp_folder = tftp_folder
        self.server = tftpy.TftpServer(tftp_folder)
        self.server.shutdown_gracefully = False

    def start_tftp_server(self):
        thr = threading.Thread(name="TFTP-Server Thread", target=self.server.listen(tftp_ip_addr, 69))
        thr.daemon = True
        thr.start()
        now_time = datetime.now()
        print(now_time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S") + ' TFTP Server: TFTP Server started')

    def stop_tftp_server(self):
        self.server.stop(True)

tftp_server = PyTFTPServer(tftp_ip_addr, tftp_folder)
tftp_server.start_tftp_server()
time.sleep(8)
tftp_server.stop_tftp_server()
```

Server don't stop as I wish. It start and continue working without any limits, also I tried use 'server timeout' (for example self.server.listen(tftp_ip_addr, 69,1)) but it is also don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code make all what I need:
    import threading
    import tftpy
    from datetime import datetime

```
def get_current_time():
    now_time = datetime.now()
    return now_time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")


class PYTFTPServer(object):
    def __init__(self, tftp_ip_addr, tftp_folder, tftp_log_level):
        self.tftp_ip_addr = tftp_ip_addr
        self.tftp_folder = tftp_folder
        self.tftp_server = tftpy.TftpServer(self.tftp_folder)
        self.tftp_log_level = tftp_log_level

    def start_tftp_server(self):
        try:
            print(get_current_time() + ' TFTP Server: TFTP Server starting')
            self.tftp_server.listen(self.tftp_ip_addr, 69)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

    def stop_tftp_server(self):
        self.tftp_server.stop()              # Do not take any new transfers, but complete the existing ones.
        print(get_current_time() + ' TFTP Server: TFTP Server stoped')
        # self.server.stop(True)            # Drop all connections and stop the server. Can be used if needed.


def start_tftp_process(tftp_ip_addr, tftp_folder, tftp_log_level):
    global tftpsrv, TFTP_srv_thread
    tftpsrv = PYTFTPServer(tftp_ip_addr, tftp_folder, tftp_log_level)
    TFTP_srv_thread = threading.Thread(name="TFTP Server thread", target=tftpsrv.start_tftp_server)
    TFTP_srv_thread.start()


def stop_tftp_process():
    tftpsrv.stop_tftp_server()
    TFTP_srv_thread.join()
```